# how to remove selected item from the list after performing autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have implemented an auto complete event using `Jquery`, and it works fine, now I need to implement a **remove** or **delete** functionality in the list I selected.
pls see the code below.

```
    $(function() {
      function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#poolName" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/DataWeb/getPoolName",
                type : 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { name_startsWith: request.term },
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                             label: item.poolName,
                             value: item.poolName
                        }
                    })); 
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
```

---

Ex : in the textBox if i type 'a' I get list of names starting with 'a', and I select 5 names starting with 'a'. It will be stored in "log" id.
    
            
                
                    Pool Name:

```
            <div style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: serif; font-size: medium;"> Result: 
                 <div> <fieldset id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;"> </fieldset> </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Now if i want to remove one of the name selected, how do i need to implement??
can anyone help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `log` function to:

**Note:** This adds a "Remove" button in front of each message, which will delete the message when clicked.

```
function log( message ) {
    var _m = '<div style="float:left;">' + message + '</div>';
    _m += '<div style="float:right;"><input type="submit" value="Remove"></div>';
    _m += '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';

    $( "<div>" ).html( _m ).prependTo( "#log" ).click(function(o){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have another doubt in this, How can i add a button next to every text, ie.. Example : I select name 'Anu' then next to anu i need a button called as remove?? I tried appending the input type button, but it takes as a string and not as html tag.

Comment: @madhu - i've modified my code to include a "Remove" button. PL. take a look.